# How to remove HomeAsUpButton arrow from ActionBar Sherlock when set an ActionView for searching?

Tags: android, search, actionbarsherlock

I know how to erase the back arrow in a normal situation using action bar Sherlock. My issue, is that I can´t erase the back arrow when it appears in a searching situation, with CollapsibleSearch.

I tried to use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` in my callback method `onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)` with no results.

Thanks!